# SharePoint PnP - Get-PnPField - Only Columns visible to Super User

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, pnp

When using `Get-PnPField`, is there a way to only pull fields that are available for editing the settings GUI?

`Get-PnPField` pulls all the fields including some system-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right by default `Get-PnPField` returns all fields from a list or site.

You can filter the results you are getting from this comment like below:

**Exclude Hidden Fields**:

```
Get-PnPField | ? { $_.Hidden -eq $false}
```

**Exclude Read Only Fields**:

```
Get-PnPField | ? { $_.ReadOnlyField -eq $false}
```

**Exclude Hidden AND Read Only Fields**:

```
Get-PnPField | ? { $_.Hidden -eq $false -AND $_.ReadOnlyField -eq $false}
```

**References**:

1. [Get-PnPField](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfield)
2. [Logical Operators in PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, this help

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-PnPField | ? { $_.Hidden -eq $false}
```

Comment: Thank you Derek, this helps